# Why indented dictionaries don't work in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I can't get my head around why this

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://ruzzle-map.herokuapp.com/bad", 
         data: { word: $(".words-list li > span.word").eq(current_word).text() },
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         jsonp: 'jsoncall' })
```

fails while this

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://ruzzle-map.herokuapp.com/bad", data: { word: $(".words-list li > span.word").eq(current_word).text() }, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: 'jsoncall' })
```

compiles well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler seems to be messing up with the indentation on the object literal, if you add a new line after the first opening brace it compiles:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://ruzzle-map.herokuapp.com/bad", 
  data: { word: $(".words-list li > span.word").eq(current_word).text() },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsoncall' 
})
```

Given that this is CoffeeScript, you can omit function call parentheses and trust indentation and newlines for the object literals instead of using braces and commas:

```
$.ajax
  url: "http://ruzzle-map.herokuapp.com/bad"
  data: 
    word: $(".words-list li > span.word").eq(current_word).text()
  dataType: 'jsonp'
  jsonp: 'jsoncall'
```

Comment: The indentation object syntax is really pretty. But I was wondering if this is a bug in the compiler...

Comment: @FiloSottile hmmm, it _might_ be, i don't know. [Here's](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%7B%20a%3A%201%0A%20%20b%3A%202%20%7D) a more basic case that reproduce the same behavior. When the new line is not indented [it seems to work fine](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%7B%20a%3A%201%0Ab%3A%202%20%7D). Indentation or white-space related bugs in general are quite tricky in CoffeeScript, as there are so many corner cases. In this case, i wouldn't be surprised if [an issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues) has already been opened (if you are able to find it hehe).